How to add Authorization while configuring webhooks in extensiv UI
I am following this extensiv doc in order to configure the webhooks for receiving the updates on our endpoint.

I see this another doc for validating the RSA signature for message validity.
Problem that I am seeing is my API endpoint is secured with Basic Auth and when I am using that endpoint in the configure webhook page in extensiv, I am not seeing any section for authorization for this endpoint. So how do I authenticate the calls coming from extensiv ?
Is there a way I can provide authorization details for my endpoint to extensiv ?

Don't see their docs mentioning anything about this. You could try if they support the "syntax" of providing the credentials in the URL - https://username:password@.... If not, then you might need to remove HTTP Auth for this endpoint.

Great ideas @CBroe but these are not feasible for us because of security concerns.

What exactly are those concerns? If you are worried a 3rd party could send fake requests, then validate the signature.
